# Sticky footer is not placed at the bottom

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, footer, sticky-footer

I'm just making some quick changes to the footer.

The footer needs to be sticky, i was following the method described by [A List Apart](http://alistapart.com/article/footers) method to try get the footer to stay at the bottom, but it seems to be off just a little bit.

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
 }
#container {
position: relative;
min-height: 100%;
}

<div id="container">
    <div id="content">...</div>
    <div id="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use the [CSSStickyFooter method](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/).

- HTML, a basic skeleton

  ```
  <div id="wrap">

      <div id="main">

      </div>

  </div>

  <div id="footer">

  </div>
  ```
- CSS, this is only a snippet

  ```
  * {margin:0;padding:0;} 

  html, body {height: 100%;}

  #wrap {min-height: 100%;}

  #main {overflow:auto;
      padding-bottom: 180px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */

  #footer {position: relative;
      margin-top: -180px; /* negative value of footer height */
      height: 180px;
      clear:both;}
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add to #wrapper clearfix, add height: 100% to #wrapper and #container in this case, you will see footer lower then should be. Now you should set top to minus height of footer and it should work. Bo I don't know if it will cover content of wrapper.

Comment: I checked it. It will cover content. But with this content it should be work good. As positioning absolute as well. In case that you will have more content just leave footer without any positioning.

Comment: If I don't add any positioning it won't be at the bottom on the homepage. Urgh! I've added clearfix to wrapper as you said.

Comment: I will be if content is bigger then height.