# Placing footer at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place my footer at the bottom of the page, not sticky. I set the bottom to 0px but when the page is too long, my footer stays on the top rather than being at the bottom of the page. Also my footer keeps on sticking with my logo instead of being at the bottom of the page. What should I do to fix this problem?

Heres an example 
[image]
CSS

```
.logo {
    display: block;
    z-index: 20;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    bottom: 0;  
}
```

HTML

```
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <h4>Follow Us On Social Media!</h4>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-3x"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div><!--End container-->
    </footer><!--End footer 2-->
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Add to footer position : fixed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sticky footer is not placed at the bottom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877482/sticky-footer-is-not-placed-at-the-bottom)

Answer (score 0):

Add position relative property to html tag and position absolute to footer as shown below and footer will be always at the bottom of the page content.

```css
html {
  min-height:100%;
  position:relative;
}

.logo {
    display: block;
    z-index: 20;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.footer {
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;  
}
```

[Check this Jsfiddle for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/Satwiks/0vsk7k3b/)